# Code help - Avoid duplicate code and rearrange

Tags: methods, java-8, code-cleanup

Following code for getting product category list for two types of product category

```
private List<Category> setCategory(CategoryContext categoryContext, CategoryWrapper categoryWrapper) {
      List<Category> categoryList = Collections.emptyList();
      if(categoryWrapper.getCategoryType() == Jewellery) {
         List<JewelleryWrapper> Prices = categoryWrapper.getJewelleryPrices();
         if (Prices != null) {
            categoryList = Prices.stream()
                        .filter(Price -> Price.getJPrice() != null)
                        .map(this::makeCategory)
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
          }
      } else if (categoryWrapper.getCategoryType() == Cloth ) { 
          List<ClothWrapper> Prices = categoryWrapper.getClothPrices();
          if (Prices != null) {
          categoryList = Prices.stream()
                        .filter(Price -> Price.getCPrice() != null)
                        .map(this::makeCategoryX)
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                }
        }
```

And `makeCategory` method looks like :

```
private CategoryItem makeCategory(JewelleryWrapper Price) {
        CategoryItem categoryItem = new CategoryItem();
        categoryItem.setId(Price.getJewelleryId());
        categoryItem.setPrice(Price.getJPrice());
        return categoryItem;
    }
```

Other will be look like  :

```
private CategoryItem makeCategoryX(ClothWrapper Price) {
            CategoryItem categoryItem = new CategoryItem();
            categoryItem.setId(Price.getClothId());
            categoryItem.setPrice(Price.getCPrice());
            return categoryItem;
        }
```

There will be two more categories to add. But I feel duplication in these code.
Can anyone please help!

Comment: Though I doubt the resolution of method reference but does overloading the `makeCategory` for different type of arguments not help here?

Comment: What is the difference between a `CategoryItem` and the `JewelleryWrapper` and `ClothWrapper` classes? All three classes seem to be just a combination of an id and a price.

Comment: but it have different product category details coming from different layers